# Python Change data structure from report

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I have the data like this:

```
data = {
'impressions': {'20190513': '50922', '20190514': '62343', '20190515': '34866'},
'clicks': {'20190513': '25', '20190514': '28', '20190515': '12'}}
```

but confused to change the structure like this:

```
[{
    'date': '20190513',
    'impressions': '50922',
    'clicks': '25',
},
{
    'date': '20190514',
    'impressions': '62343',
    'clicks': '28',
},
{
    'date': '20190515',
    'impressions': '34866',
    'clicks': '12',
}]
```

I have tried several times but failed. Help me please. Thank's...

Comment: `I have tried several times but failed`. Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 3):

Using a list and dict comprehension. Works in Python 2 & 3:

```
from pprint import pprint
d = [{'date': date, 'impressions': data['impressions'][date], 'clicks': data['clicks'][date]} for date in data['clicks']]
pprint(d)
```

Output:

```
[{'clicks': '25', 'date': '20190513', 'impressions': '50922'},
 {'clicks': '28', 'date': '20190514', 'impressions': '62343'},
 {'clicks': '12', 'date': '20190515', 'impressions': '34866'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Dictionary, [items()](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques) method returns the list with all dictionary keys with values

```
data = {
'impressions': {'20190513': '50922', '20190514': '62343', '20190515': '34866'},
'clicks': {'20190513': '25', '20190514': '28', '20190515': '12'}}

impressions = data['impressions']
clicks = data['clicks']

list1 = []
for key,value in impressions.items():
    dict1 = {}

    dict1['date'] = key
    dict1['impressions'] = value
    #check key exist in clicks dictionary
    if key in clicks:
        dict1['clicks'] = clicks[key]

    list1.append(dict1)

print(list1)
```

O/P:

```
[{'date': '20190513', 'impressions': '50922', 'clicks': '25'}, {'date': '20190514', 'impressions': '62343', 'clicks': '28'}, {'date': '20190515', 'impressions': '34866', 'clicks': '12'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
data = {
'impressions': {'20190513': '50922', '20190514': '62343', '20190515': '34866'},
'clicks': {'20190513': '25', '20190514': '28', '20190515': '12'}}

result = []
for i in data['impressions'].keys():
    result.append({'date': i, 'impressions': data['impressions'][i], 'clicks': data['clicks'][i]})

print(result)
```

This is my result:

```
[{'date': '20190513', 'impressions': '50922', 'clicks': '25'}, {'date': '20190514', 'impressions': '62343', 'clicks': '28'}, {'date': '20190515', 'impressions': '34866', 'clicks': '12'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
data = {
'impressions': {'20190513': '50922', '20190514': '62343', '20190515': '34866'},
'clicks': {'20190513': '25', '20190514': '28', '20190515': '12'}}

result = [{"date":key,"impressions":value,"clicks":data["clicks"][key]} for key,value in data["impressions"].items()]

print(result)
```